# call Function.prototype.call.apply inside for loop

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, prototype

My goal is iterate through a list of functions and call each function in turn.  I'd like to avoid an anonymous function but I'm having a hard time figuring out where I am going wrong (using underscore but the principle should be pretty similar regardless)

```
function wait() {
  console.log("wait")
}

function more() {
  console.log("more")
}

_.each([wait, more], Function.prototype.call.apply)
```

Unfortunately, this errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function
```

I believe this is due to the fact that the iterator func is called with three arguments (item, index, array) and Function.prototype.call.apply requires null as the second argument in this case, not an index.

When I try this, it fails with a new error

```
_.each([wait, more], _.partial(Function.prototype.call.apply, _, null)) 

Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on [object Window], which is a object and not a function
```

Finally, this works

```
unary = function(func) {
    return function(a) {
      return func.apply(a);
    };
};

_.each([wait, more], unary(_.partial(Function.prototype.call)))
```

Comment: You're only passing `.apply`, which has no relationship to `.call` unless you actually invoke it instead of pass it. So you'd need `.bind()` to secure that relationship... `_.each([wait, more], Function.apply.bind(Function.call))`, but this isn't right either since you're iterating the Array, not passing it. Therefore, you'd need `_.each([wait, more], Function.call.bind(Function.call))`, and that'll work.

Comment: this explanation was brilliant.  I am only passing apply.  I am correct in understanding that, through the binding, each is effectively going to call Function.call(arguments) for each item?

Comment: Yes, but where `.call` has a bound `this`, so it is effectively doing `Function.call.call(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])`, where  the arguments are `item, i, array`. So `Function.call.call(item, i, array)` is just like `item.call(i, array)`, so if you log the `this` and the first argument in your functions, that should be what you get.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Wish I could upvote your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
_.each([wait, more], function(f){ f(); });
```

Or even this:

```
_.each([wait, more], function(f){ f.call(); });
```

**Update:** Then try this:

```
_.each([wait, more], Function.prototype.call, Function.prototype.call)
```

Bind the context using third argument, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhkcm4m1/). Check [the doc](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Comment: My goal is to avoid anonymous functions. At a deeper level, I want to understand why Function.prototype.call.apply does not work as the callback to _.each